# Is it possible to post images on Facebook with tags? As one normally does while posting an image

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

1. Got the photos URL from GRAPH API
2. Able to add a pic to albums  (me/photos)
3. What next for tagging ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes tagging is possible.

1. There are 2 parameters that you have to include in your `POST` request, for implementing tags.
2. `place` : You have to use `place` as a parameter and pass an `id` to it, it is compulsory for using tags in `facebook api`. For example : `place=abcd` , here `abcd` can be id of any place or even any page on facebook.
3. `tags` : You can then assign desired friend ids (comma seperated values) in this `tag` parameter.

It is also referred [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/)